# I want the text between the last /th> and /tbody>

Tags: regex, vb.net, html-table

This is what I use

```
    output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(output, "(?s)/th>(.*?)</tbody>", "$1")
```

Notice that I am using (.*?) because I want the search to be ungreedy. That is there are severals /th> around. I want to get rid texts above the LAST /th>

This is what I got.

```
<!-- statistics_period -->


<input name="subForm" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="hidTotal" type="hidden" value="886">

<div class="domlistframe">
<div class="divMainListingTable">
<table width="76%" align="left" class="mainListTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tbody><tr>
                                                                        <th nowrap="">&nbsp;<               
                                                        <th colspan="4">&nbsp;</th>



        <th id="sercol" nowrap="" colspan="11">Totals</th>
```

You see? Several /th> there.

Yes I know full well the horrible consequences of parsing html with regular expression as described here [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

I am parsing mostly table anyway. It's working

**Note:** here is a simpler problem that's equivalent with above
Say I have a text like this

```
cow cow cow chicken cat cow cat dog hello bla.
```

Say I want `cat dog hello`. That is text between the last cow and bla.

What would be the regular expression for that?

Notice I want the text between the LAST **cow** and **bla**.

Doing it

```
cow.*bla
```

will give me the whole text

Doing it `cow.?*bla` should give me what I want. However, as you can see from the sample I uses, it didn't work.

Comment: *This is what I use* <- in what? where?

Comment: in vb.net in a code. So output is a large html and I want a part of that html between the last /th and the the </tbody>

Answer (score 2):

### HINT

Try the pattern:

```
.*cow((?!cow).*?)bla
```

for the `cow..bla` problem.

The leading `.*` skips everything until the last `cow` is encountered

Comment: What does (?!cow) match?

Comment: @JimThio It forces the captured group `((?!cow).*?)` to not have the word cow in it. `(?!` defines a negative lookahead.

Comment: Actually that's what I am looking for. It turns out it's not even necessary. Any reference what ?! is.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer. Basically I solved the problem by using the technique hjpotter92 uses.

What I did is

```
    output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(output, "(?s).*/th>(.*?)</tbody>", "$1")
```

Because the first .* is greedy. It will automatically match the maximum string that contains .*th>

Some question remains. Why my original code doesn't work?

I suspect it has something to do with regular expression works from left to right. Again any input would be fine.

I would also thank htpotter for telling me what complement operator in regex is.

Hmmm... Well, this answer does answer the question of what should I do to make it work and now it's working. However, it's based on other answer. Which one I should pick as answer?